# Отправка формы вместе с файлом в php

Tags: php

Подскажите, в чём ошибка? Отправляю форму через аякс в обработчик:

```
<form id="sendmsg" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!-- фотка -->
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="files">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-secondary"><?echo $lang->selectphoto;?></button>
<!-- фотка -->

<textarea id="textarea" class="uk-textarea standart" name="message" maxlength="1500" required></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="send" value="&#10148;" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary send-button" id="sendbtn">

</form>
```

Аякс:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() { 
    $("#sendmsg").submit(function(send){
        send.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'updates/sendmsg.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'files': $('#files')[0].files[0],'idtodb':'<?php echo $partnerid ?>', 'message':$('textarea[name="message"]').val()},
            success: function(html){  
                document.getElementById("sendmsg").reset();
                $("#globalresult").html(html);
            }  
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Без выбора фото всё работает правильно, а если выбрать фото, то в консоли ругается на это:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:73313)
    at Dt (jquery.min.js:2:73205)
    at Dt (jquery.min.js:2:73228)
    at S.param (jquery.min.js:2:73524)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2:76904)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (chat?id=23:509:11)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43090)
    at v.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41074)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте объект FormData. Примерно так:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() { 
    $("#sendmsg").submit(function(send){
        send.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData;
        formData.append('files', $('#files')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('idtodb', '<?php echo $partnerid ?>');
        formData.append('message', $('textarea[name="message"]').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'updates/sendmsg.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(html){  
                document.getElementById("sendmsg").reset();
                $("#globalresult").html(html);
            }  
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```